# Double iterated integrals -- area

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Sketch the region bounded by $y=\ln x$, $y=2\ln x$, $x=e$ in the first quadrant. Then express the region's area as an iterated double integral and evaluate it.

So my idea was to do $\int_1^2 \int_0^{\ln x} dx dy$ and I found that that was $2\ln2 - 1. $

But for the other portion, I decided to do: $\int_2^e \int_{e^(\frac{e}2)}^{e^y} dy dx $ and I'm getting $e^e - e^2 - 2e^{\frac{e}{2}} - 2e$.

Can somebody confirm that those 2 answers added together are correct or what I did wrong?

Comment: Is there a typo? There should not be a $y$ in your result for the second integral.

Comment: yea let me fix that sorry

Comment: Why are there two portions? Isn't this basically a curvy triangle from $x=1$ to $x=e$ and from $y = \ln x$ to $y = 2\ln x$? Maybe I am visualizing it wrong.

Comment: Just one portion - see V. Rossetto's answer below.

Comment: never mind figured out thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer:

This can be understood as the region $D=\{(x,y), 1\leq x\leq \mathrm e, \ln x\leq y\leq 2\ln x \}$.
That would give the area
$$\mathcal A=\int_1^{\mathrm e}\left(\int_{\ln x}^{2\ln x}\mathrm dy\right)\mathrm dx.$$
You can check that it is equal to $1$.

Comment: it's supposed to be the first quadrant right? So shouldn't the x bounds be from 1 to 2? or e?

Comment: The first quadrant means, I suppose, that one should only take $D_2$ then... I will edit my answer.

Comment: Right, but the question is asking me to do this with an iterated double integral? Doesn't that mean that I have to do 2 double integrals?

Comment: @user127778. No I don't think so. Iterated integrals simply means that the boundaries of the second one depend on the variable of the first.

Comment: you're right, just wanted to make sure -- thank you!